# WPF : change <views:ParentView /> using code behind

Tags: wpf, xaml, window

I am trying to include a child `Window` into parent (another `Window`) in one `Page`, when I use in XAML I know I can use this one:

```
<views:ParentView Width="550" Height="250" />
```

But, is there possible to change an XAML code from:

```
<views:ParentView Width="550" Height="250"/>
```

Into code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XAML you can use `StackPanel`:

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel" />
```

And in code behind following code to add new control to main view:

```
   myStackPanel.Children.Add(new ParentView() { Width = 550, Height = 250 });
```

Comment: i can't use that, i need another way (in behind code) from this xaml code : < views:ParentView Width="550" Height="250"/>

Comment: @KizuHikaru check my answer again.

Comment: Thanks, but still. it doesn't work, i guess cause my ParentView is Window and not a Children so it will throw an exception (Cannot add Window as a child of Visual.) when i am trying to add the ParentView as Children to myStackPanel.

Comment: @KizuHikaru you can change `ParentView` to `UserControl` and everything will be ok.